# How to fix VS2013: Error: type or namespace 'Windows' could not be found?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I want to create a service for Wifi Direct. If I try to add Reference, I don't see core->windows option in VS2013. I have updated the winSDK. 
How do I add the Windows.Devices.WifiDirect api ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
public sealed class WiFiDirectDevice : IDisposable
```

this is a sample code to handle connections

```
   Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectDevice wfdDevice;
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<String> Connect(string deviceId)
{
    string result = ""; 

    try
    {
        // No device Id specified.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceId)) { return "Please specify a Wi- Fi Direct device Id."; }

        // Connect to the selected Wi-Fi Direct device.
        wfdDevice = await Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId);

        if (wfdDevice == null)
        {
            result = "Connection to " + deviceId + " failed.";
        }

        // Register for connection status change notification.
        wfdDevice.ConnectionStatusChanged += new TypedEventHandler<Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectDevice, object>(OnConnectionChanged);

        // Get the EndpointPair information.
        var EndpointPairCollection = wfdDevice.GetConnectionEndpointPairs();

        if (EndpointPairCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            var endpointPair = EndpointPairCollection[0];
            result = "Local IP address " + endpointPair.LocalHostName.ToString() + 
                " connected to remote IP address " + endpointPair.RemoteHostName.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
           result = "Connection to " + deviceId + " failed.";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        // Handle error.
        result = "Error occurred: " + err.Message;
    }

    return result;
}

private void OnConnectionChanged(object sender, object arg)
{
    Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectConnectionStatus status = 
        (Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectConnectionStatus)arg;

    if (status == Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect.WiFiDirectConnectionStatus.Connected)
    {
        // Connection successful.
    }
    else
    {
        // Disconnected.
        Disconnect();
    }
}

private void Disconnect()
{
    if (wfdDevice != null) 
    {
        wfdDevice.Dispose(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this be after the fact. I need to add Windows in references still right? i don't see the option of adding that. sorry for the newbie questions, i am not used to Visual studios.

Comment: You need to enable the Proximity capability in your app manifest file in order to use the Wi-Fi Direct API.